# Datagridview on winform doesn't paint backcolor

Tags: winforms, datagridview

On a winform I refresh a datagridview. This triggers `protected override void OnCellFormatting(DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)` [two times] of my subclassed datagridview and the backcolor of my datagridviewcell gets the correct backcolor.

However this color is not painted, it is only painted when I click in the cell. The mouse click again fires `protected override void OnCellFormatting` [4 times].

Is this behaviour to be expected? Can it be changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the backcolor on the CellFormatting event:

```
private void myDataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = myDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```